# ZSCAN guarantee for elements which score has changed during iteration

Tags: redis

I cannot find this information in the documentation: Does Redis guarantee that an element is returned with ZSCAN command under this condition:

> The element was contained in the sorted set from the start to the end
>   of a full iteration, BUT the score of such element has changed (even
>   several times, for instance by another client) during iteration?

Only related statement I found regarding this is the following:

> Elements that were not constantly present in the collection during a
>   full iteration, may be returned or not: it is undefined.

But I don't know if score change in such case is the same thing as remove/add operations or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the element exists during the full iteration, it will be returned by the `zscan` command. It doesn't matter whether the score has been changed during the iteration.

Normally, `zset` is implemented as a hash table (i.e. Redis' `dict`), and a skiplist. When running the `zscan` command, it iterates over the hash table entries to do the scan job. The changing of the score (value of the dict entry) won't affect the iteration process.

If `zset` is small enough, Redis implements it as a `ziplist`. In this case, Redis returns all elements in a single `zscan` call. So the score CANNOT be changed during the iteration.

In a word, you have the guarantee.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot **for_stack** for the confirmation. I didn't know if someone will response so meanwhile I implemented some own checks in Java:

```
@Test
public void testZScanGuaranteeWithScoreUpdates() {
    try (Jedis jedis = jedisPool.getResource()) {
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 50).forEach(i -> testZScanGuaranteeWithUpdates(jedis, false));
        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 50).forEach(i -> testZScanGuaranteeWithUpdates(jedis, true));
    }
}

/**
 * Changing score of elements (named ids) during iteration (eventually inserting and removing another unchecked ids)
 * and then assert that no element (id) is missing
 */
private void testZScanGuaranteeWithUpdates(Jedis jedis, boolean noise) {
    Random ran = new Random();
    List<String> noiseIds = IntStream.range(0, 4000).mapToObj(i -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()).collect(toList());
    if (noise) { // insert some noise with random score (from 0 to 5000)
        noiseIds.forEach(id -> jedis.zadd(KEY, ran.nextInt(5000), id));
    }

    int totalIds = 2000;
    List<String> ids = IntStream.range(0, totalIds).mapToObj(i -> UUID.randomUUID().toString()).collect(toList());
    Set<String> allScanned = new HashSet<>();

    ids.forEach(id -> jedis.zadd(KEY, ran.nextInt(2500) + 1000, id)); // insert all IDs with random score (from 1000 to 3500)

    redis.scanIds(KEY, 100, res -> { // encapsulate iteration step - this closure is executed for every 100 elements during iteration
        allScanned.addAll(res); // record 100 scanned ids
        Collections.shuffle(ids);
        ids.stream().limit(500).forEach(id -> jedis.zadd(KEY, ran.nextInt(2500) + 1000, id)); // change score of 500 random ids
        if (noise) { // insert and remove some noise
            IntStream.range(0, 50).forEach(i -> jedis.zadd(KEY, ran.nextInt(5000), UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
            IntStream.range(0, 60).forEach(i -> jedis.zrem(KEY, noiseIds.get(ran.nextInt(noiseIds.size()))));
        }
    });

    if (!noise) {
        assertEquals(totalIds, allScanned.size()); // 2000 unique ids scanned
    }
    assertTrue(allScanned.containsAll(ids)); // none id is missing

    jedis.del(KEY); // prepare for test re-execution
}
```

Tests are passing, i.e. all elements are returned by ZSCAN even when their score has changed during iteration using ZADD command.